# can´t drop parent table referened by a foreign key contraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I made some tables with knex

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('login_user', table => {
        table.increments('id').unsigned().primary();
        table.string('email').notNullable();
        table.unique('email');
        table.string('password_digest').notNullable();
    });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('login_user');
};
```

And

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('login_software', table => {
      table.increments('id').unsigned().primary();
      table.string('name').notNullable();
      table.integer('login_user_id').unsigned().notNullable().references('id').inTable('login_user').onDelete('CASCADE').index();
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('login_software');
};
```

If I make `drop table login_user` shouldn´t the `cascade` let me delete login_user and delete login_software in the process?

Comment: `CASCADE` means that when you **delete a row** on the parent table, the related "children" rows on the other one are deleted. It doesn't work for **dropping tables**.

Answer (score 0):

Cascade doesn't help in this case, since it only tells what to do to a certain foreign key reference when the row that it is referencing is deleted.

To be able to drop the table to which foreign key is referencing to you need to drop the foreign key constraint first.